# CSS - Opacity to main element not to pseudo-elements (::after, ::before)

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I have got `span` with `::after` pseudo-element:

```css
#someId {
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 36px;
color: red;
}
#someId::after {
content: 'B';
}
```

```html
<span id="someId">A</span>
```

I want to make the `::after` element visible, while hiding the main element. I tried to use `opacity` and `filter: opacity` and `visibility`, but that didn't work. How can I achieve the desired behaviour **without manipulating the `color` property, while keeping the text selectable**?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can't do it.  You could try a hack with absolute positioning or scaling, but the opacity trick like you want it doesn't work

Comment: @lumio Yes, but i won't to manipulate `color` property.

Comment: Essentially, you can't **and keep the span text selectable**.

Comment: Pseudo-elements from `::after` & `::before` are not part of the DOM so there are a ton of properties, and methods that do not "see" them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use opacity 0 on element, but opacity 1 on pseudo element.

But you can use diffrent visibility values in elements and pseudo elements.

```css
.lorem {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.lorem::before {
  visibility: visible;
  content: 'Lorem';
}
```

```html
<p class="lorem">ipsum</p>
```

Comment: Why is not possible to "use opacity 0 on element, but opacity 1 on pseudo element"?